# How to add a simple design in classic editor plugin creating post page through another Wp plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to add simple html form without breaking the extisiting design or license of Classic Editor plugin which is GPLv2

I added simple code in classic-edior.php file (I'm not sure If it's the best way but I'm making a wp-plugin that must this simple form comes in Classic Edior creating post page so I can't use adding short code maybe?.

```
function myfunction()
{
    // after this next, plain HTML
?>
    <!-- HTML !-->

    <!-- HTML !-->

    <div style="      ">

        <button class="button-2" role="button" style=" display: flex; margin-left:25%;  justify-content: center; ">Button</button>

        <form action="/action_page.php" style="   margin: auto; width: 50%;border: 3px solid black; padding: 10px;">
            <label for="fname">Action:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value=" "><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>


    <!-- more HTML code here -->
    <?php   // back to PHP
    // .. some more PHP stuff
    return;
}
myfunction();
```

[image: a]

Comment: you should use hooks and filters, never modify plugins or WP itself directly or your changes will be destroyed when you install updates. Can you add context for what you're doing? Why are you adding a form and what is the purpose of the form?

Comment: @TomJNowell The purpose of the form is implmeneting php function that php curl code to send API call to getting the data from the API then paste into a text area that will be under the form or paste it of the `text area of creating post of Classic Editor itself`

Comment: Can I know what are the related hook and filters that related to this page and enables me to add code in this part with the design I want, thanks for answering.

Comment: if you can describe in the same way you would describe to a non-technical user, _then_ use technical terms. Otherwise we have to work backwards from your description to figure out what it actually does. Have you tried creating a metabox instead? This isn't something you can do with a form that actually submits, it has to be done in javascript and only javascript or your form will never work no matter where you place it on the page, or wether it's done using hooks filters or by modifying the plugin

Comment: also, you need to avoid making AJAX and form requests to standalone PHP files, your `action_page.php` is a massive security problem, and will cause issues, standalone PHP files are a development dead end and the opposite of what you need to do to achieve your goal here

Comment: probably I can't use javascript in this case because the API keys will exposed in the html and browser files, so I have to use PHP and I maybe find someway equalize the returned data from the API to Js variable and print into the text area.

Comment: i didn't say you can't use AJAX, I said specifically standalone files. There are at least 2 standardised APIs for AJAX in WordPress, e.g. the REST API and the legacy admin AJAX API. Both are safer and more compatible than a standalone file, especially the REST API which gives you validation/sanitisation/authentication arguments and a pretty URL. WP is a CMS you should make your requests to WP and then handle them in code, but never make direct requests standalone PHP files in a theme or plugin. That also means your `<form>` tag is unnecessary, but you do need to enqueue some JS

Comment: I got it thanks, so I'm gonna change the type of input to  `<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="API_call">` then catch the request when `isset['API_call']` but sorry the form is just an example not completed just more concerned about the way that I add the attached code the in `/wp-admin/post-new.php` page

Comment: Also for Ajax for sure I'm gonna use Ajax that are related to the WordPress.

Comment: So how can I add this piece of html code in Classic Editor page with breaking some other things, I searched about related hooks but couldn't find something related.

Comment: the non-AJAX form submission will never work, because it'll discard the page and generate it afresh, giving you a brand new problem of how to insert the new information into the new post page ( and how to recover any changes that were destroyed when the form was submitted ). A pure PHP implementation of what you want is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to do the following:

- add a metabox with a text input and a button ( give them unique IDs )
- enqueue a javascript file
- in your javascript file, look for the input and button by the unique ID you gave them

  - when the button is pressed, look up the inputs value, and make your AJAX request, jQuery should be enough to do this if you're unsure how
  - if it's successful, replace the content in the TinyMCE field using the standard javascript APIs
- you will also need to implement an AJAX handler, either as a REST API endpoint, or via the old `admin-ajax.php` API. This is what makes the request to your API ( also why use curl when WordPress has a more portable wrapper around it with `wp_remote_get`/`wp_remote_post` and the `WP_HTTP` API )

There are quite a few parts here, each of which are covered already on the official dev docs and in questions other people have already asked and answered on the site. If you are unsure how to do any of the steps, search this stack or the official WP documentation for that smaller step.

Important notes:

- never make direct browser requests to PHP files in your plugin or theme
- never modify plugins you didn't write yourself
- you don't need to modify the classic editor plugin to add metaboxes, any plugin can do that
- you don't need the classic editor plugin to make custom post types not use the block editor
- you could replace all the blocks in the block editors content in a 1 liner, using the classic editor does not make this task easier ( and the block editor will show a custom metabox in the sidebar anyway )

Comment: Thanks, but I still have no idea which best way to add the meta box with the button so the flow OR specifically where should I enqueue the JS file to be displayed in `/wp-admin/post-new.php` (btw I assume I can't even change the file due to licnese but not the big deal currently). 

The user click the button >>  Ajax request with the metabox data >> PHP API function called then the data will printed in creating post text are

Comment: Thanks for letting me know It's first time to know WP provide POST/GET requests like `wp_remote_post`

Comment: there is only one single way to add a custom metabox to the classic editor, there is no choice of solutions, and it's been asked on this stack many times. Once you have your metabox, put a text input tag and a button inside it. Unfortunately, telling you each and every single step in meticulous detail in a single answer would take me hours of writing that has already been done elsewhere in much greater detail. I doubt the answer box can even contain such an answer. 1. put a text box and a button in a metabox. 2. load JS on the post editor screen 3. in that JS do an AJAX call on button press

Comment: all 3 of those steps have easy solutions that are well documented and are each a good question on their own, and have already been asked on this stack.

Comment: e.g. for how to add a meta box, the function is literally called `add_meta_box`, and the examples on the official wp.org dev site answer another question you had by accident: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_meta_box/

Comment: and the official documentation even has a page dedicated to metaboxes, including an AJAX section https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/

Comment: Thanks it works.

Comment: Is there a way to make a custom design for the metabox that I just added also to be above the original section of `Add New Post`